# JSP Login getParameter return null

Tags: java, database, jsp, authentication

I'm make simple login page use jsp

my problem is getParameter is always null

this is my mainpage.jsp code

```
<form action = "LoginProcess.jsp" method = "post">  
    <table align="center">
    <tr>
    <td><label for="userid">ID : </label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="userid" id="userid"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label for="userpw">PW : </label></td>
    <td><input type="password" name="userpw" id="userpw"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
    <input type="hidden" name="status">
    <input type="button" name="join" class="loingbtn" value="">
    <input type="button" name="find" class="loingbtn" value="">
    <input type="button" name="booking" class="loingbtn" value="">
    <input type="button" name="msg" class="loingbtn" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="login" class="loginbtn" value="">
</form>
```

This is loginprocess.jsp

```
<body>
    <jsp:useBean id = "brd" class = "mainpage.LoginUser" scope="page"/>
    <jsp:useBean id = "brddb" class = "mainpage.UserDB" scope="page"/>
    <%          
        String id = request.getParameter("userid");
        String passwd = request.getParameter("userpw");
        if ((brddb.isLogin(id, passwd))) {  
    %>
    <script>
        alert("Success");
    </script>
    <%
        }else{
            %>
            <script>
            alert("Fail");
            self.close();
            </script>
            <%
        }
%>
```

this two variable is alaway null

```
String id = request.getParameter("userid");
String passwd = request.getParameter("userpw");
```

what can i do

Comment: remove this 2 lines n check if it works ` <jsp:useBean id = "brd" class = "mainpage.LoginUser" scope="page"/>
    <jsp:useBean id = "brddb" class = "mainpage.UserDB" scope="page"/>`

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone I'm use brdbd class under line so i can't remove that line

Comment: ok fine,just check if in those 2 classes u r setting id,passwd to null..

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone oh.... Thank's you 
LoginUser.java has String id that is null

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone 
so i'm use setter getter
solved that problem 
thank's you

Comment: so u got d answer right?I am putting it as an answer..plz tick it

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone
Thank's you i'm check your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether in these 2 classes

```
    <jsp:useBean id = "brd" class = "mainpage.LoginUser" scope="page"/>
    <jsp:useBean id = "brddb" class = "mainpage.UserDB" scope="page"/>
```

you are setting id and psswd to null.

That could be the only reason you are getting null.